# Open Graph produces "http://invalid.invalid/" for shared page

Tags: wordpress, twitter, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to make FB, Twitter, and Google+ produce the correct data for my site. So far, when I click on the FB share button, I get a message that says "http://invalid.invalid/". I thought I followed the instructions for this, but maybe I left something out. Can someone help me out?

HEAD

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Open Graph data -->
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/share.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Site Title"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Site Description"/>

    <!-- Twitter Card data -->
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Site Title">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="Site Description">
    <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/share.jpg">

    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Just+Another+Hand" rel="stylesheet">

    <?php mp3j_addscripts(); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

HTML

```
<div id="sharing">
    <a target="_blank" class="fb_share" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?> /&title=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook"></a>
    <a target="_blank" class="twitter_share" href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_title(); ?>+<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>" title="Share on Twitter"></a>
    <a target="_blank" class="gplus_share" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>" title="Share on Google Plus"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a test link for us?

Comment: @luschn Yes, just included one in the post above. The share links are at the very top right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Open Graph Tags look good:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.keebs.com%2F

sharer.php only takes the URL as parameter though, so this would be correct:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.keebs.com
```

Comment: I just changed it to that but it still says `http://invalid.invalid/` when I try to share. But I realize that it looks correct in the linter. So what's going on?

Comment: you are still including the title as it seems, and there is a blank in the url too. remove this part: " /&title=Welcome to The Mobile Mix"